# Does pdfium library code CPDF_Annot can implement remove specific annotation in pdf file?

Tags: annotations, pdfium

I an researching the way to remove or modify a specfic annotation in pdf file, our project use the pdfium library, I wonder is anyone familiar with this? I just want to find whether I can remove or modify specfic annotation in pdf file? YES or NO is enough.

Answer (score 0):

There is now an API in PDFium to remove annotations. See FPDFPage_RemoveAnnot in fpdf_annot.h

As an aside, you should not be using the internal classes, they can be moved, changed and refactored without warning. The public/ API is the only API which can be considered stable.